# Dynamic _Hosts.cshtml file in Blazor with C# code

Tags: blazor

Just used the great free Blazor code of DevExpress to implement custom `<HEAD>` data on runtime:

_Hosts.cshtml (see the code snippet in  element):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<DocumentMetadataComponent>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
    </head>
    <body>
        <app>
            @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
        </app>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
```

Works great so far (can make title, description, etc. dynamic).

Problem now is that I have to set some variables on that top Level to overgive and interpret once.
I want to know the used url and give some data dynamically.

But with my knowledge right now I just can do it twice in each component (DocumentMetadataComponent + App).

I'm getting data in MainLayout.razor:

```
<CascadingValue Value="StoreData" Name="StoreData">
    @Body
</CascadingValue>

@code{
    public StoreCompleteDTO StoreData { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        using var tl = new TimeLogger($"MainLayout.razor OnInitializedAsync()");

        StoreData = await AppState.GetStoreData(My.StoreId);
    }
}
```

This StoreData variable must be available in dynamic meta data, because I have to choose different CSS files for other stores...

Hope the explanation is clear.

Goal is call this just ONCE:
    StoreData = await AppState.GetStoreData(My.StoreId);

because it is web service call and costs time...

Thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest the best way to make some information available across a Blazor application is to use the service system and Dependency Injection.

This means you can control the scope of the data (global? session?) as well as make it available on any page/component you need. Writing in the form of State container will also help in usage. Here is a quick sample that just sets the page title, but you can extend it to cover `<meta>` for example.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// A state container for head tags
    /// </summary>
    public class HeadState
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Page title
        /// </summary>
        public string Title => _title;

        // internal store
        private string _title = "";

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the page title
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="title"></param>
        public void SetTitle(string title)
        {
            if(!string.Equals(_title,title))
            {
                _title = title;
                HeadChanged?.Invoke();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event raised when data changes
        /// </summary>
        public event Action HeadChanged;
    }
```

The `HeadState` class is a state container to allow us to set the page title. The title property is read-only so it has to be set via SetTitle, which triggers the `HeadChanged` event so consumers know it's amended. We need to register this as a scoped service in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
   // declare the HeadState for DI
   services.AddScoped<State.HeadState>();
```

To implement it, we amend the `_host.cshtml` to add a component that renders it in the `<head>` section as per your question:

```html
<head>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<HeadComponent>(RenderMode.Server))
</head>
```

The `HeadComponent` injects the state and handles the render and updates:

```
@inject State.HeadState head

<title>@head.Title</title>

@code
{
    // although the title is set on loading, if it is changed by a component we
    // need to call StateHasChanged to trigger Blazor to rerender since the event
    // that triggered it is outside this component
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        head.HeadChanged += () =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        };
    }
}
```

To test it on a page (or any other component!) we just inject the state object and use it

```
@page "/"
@inject State.HeadState head

<h1>Head Demo</h1>

<button @onclick='(()=> head.SetTitle("Hello"))'>Set title to Hello</button>
<button @onclick='(()=> head.SetTitle("World"))'>Set title to World</button>
```

Here we are just doing a `<title>` tag for demo purposes but of course you can add `<meta>` or other values. I'd avoid amending CSS stylesheets though as that possibly should be done via JS but I'm not 100% sure that's correct.

Comment: Thank you Quango, very helpful! The only open issue is how you would change CSS path dynamically. You wrote via JS, but where to inject here on server side blazor? I'm analyzing the baseUrl and match a Store to it. Each Store has its own CSS, so I want to tell as early as possible which CSS to use. When doing in the component it of course is flickering at the first time. Any idea how to get it "smooth" to inject a CSS in server side Blazor? Thx!

Comment: @baer999 You can extend this model to add CSS. Typically we add CSS as `<link rel='stylesheet' href='....' type='text/css' >` in the `<head>` tag. So add a readonly list of CSS URLs to the `HeadState`, an `AddStylesheet` method, then in the `HeadComponent` you'd add the `<link` tags

Comment: Hello @Quango, what about correct search indexing of google? When I make the Title etc. flexible (ServerPreRender Mode), will it be available for Google etc. in a correct way or is it a problem for SEO & Co.? Thx!

Comment: @baer999 if a page is pre-rendered then search bots should record the correct title, but SEO is a big problem for most SPAs. However, in my case most of the content is in a secure app so search bots cannot see it anyway, so it's not an issue for me.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work in ServerPrerendered mode? I get the following: The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.

Comment: @TrystanWilcock have not tried that but this is really a solution for Server-Side Blazor since it requires a `_host.cshtml` as the template layout. `ServerPrerendered` mode doesn't make much sense in this context as it's server rendered already - it wouldn't change the content. If you're looking to use WASM this approach won't work - you're better waiting for .NET 5 which has this capability built-in

Comment: @Quango I ended up using the following package which allows me to change metadata perfectly in my ServerPrerendered app! Also works for Server and WASM too. https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.HeadElement